# jQuery off() implementation not working

Tags: events, event-handling, jquery

What am I doing wrong here? I read the docs but I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working as intended.

```
    $(".img-edit-button").on("click", function () {
       if(self.elementMenuOpen === false){
           self.showImageMenu();
           self.elementMenuOpen = true;
       }else{
           self.hideImageMenu();
           self.elementMenuOpen = false;
       }
});
```

Then later, I use `off()`

```
$(".img-edit-button").off();
```

But the events seem to be doubling up even after using `.off()` is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo in the example

Comment: And which events are you turning off? `.off('click')`

Comment: Where does your `self` variable come from?

Comment: the latest docs have this "At minimum, either a namespace or event name must be provided." http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: Is there only one item with the `img-edit-button` class?

Comment: @LiviuT. Isn't $(".img-edit-button") the namespacE?

Comment: It is hard to figure out what is happening without more context.  Can you include more of your code to show when and how this code is called?

Comment: @Sashenka yes there is only one

Comment: @LiviuT. It does say that but then gives an example of "removing all handlers" that takes no parameter.  Seems to be an issue with the docs, contradicts itself.

Comment: @JamesMontagne The function that contains the off() script is definitely being called, so it comes down to the implementation of off().

Comment: @ChrisB. Are you sure that your code that is binding to the click event is not being executed multiple times?

Comment: @JustinBicknell that's what I am using off() for, I am trying to keep the event handlers from being stacked once that "click" event handler is called again.

Comment: @ChrisB This is straight from http://api.jquery.com/off/ "The off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on()". So if you bind a click event after off is called, they will continue to be executed

Comment: I am not that good with Jquery but did you try `$(".img-edit-button").off().on(//your code here);` ? It would unbind the event before each binding.

Comment: @Sashenka that would work

Answer (score 6):

This is straight from http://api.jquery.com/off/ "The off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on()". So if you bind a click event after off is called, they will continue to be executed. I am guessing you are re-binding to the click event multiple times.

One solution would be to bind the event to a parent, **only once**, so you don't have to re-bind every time the elements in question are added/removed from the dom.  I understand this may have some performance concerns, but keeping your parent class as deep in the dom as possible will help with this.

```
$(".someparentclass").on('click','.img-edit-button',function(){});
```

Or if you want to re-bind you could use the following:

```
$(".img-edit-button").off().on(function(){});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SEndX/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use some "toggle" function to show and hide a menu. The options you can find [here](http://api.jquery.com/?s=toggle).

Comment: toggle is not applicable in this case, I am trying to remove the event handler "click" so that it does not stack up when called again.

Answer (score 0):

Old but just figured someone might still run across this. If you are going to call the off it not work if nothing is assigned. It won't always trigger an error but it will stop the code from executing correctly. On the page load make sure to add a blank on event. $('#selector').on();
Works for me any way.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me, added the empty $(..).on();  on de document ready method.

Answer (score 0):

There are some cases where you don't want to bind an event directly to an element. Rather, you want to bind it to a parent element, like "body" for example. This is essential when you want to define your event listeners globally but the element may not exist yet:

```
$("body").on("mouseenter", ".hover-item", function() {
    // do the thing
}
```

The problem here is if you try to run `.off()` on `.hover-item` it doesn't work. Alternatively, if you try to use `.off()` on `body`, using `.children()` doesn't do anything either.

Instead of using `.off()`, I believe it's best practice to bind your events to a particular class name, and when you want to disable those events, remove the class name:

```
$(".the-element").removeClass(".hover-item");
```

Now that particular element won't have the event listener enabled anymore. However, since you technically defined the event listener on `body`, if you need to enable the hover effect again at some later time, you can just use `addClass(".hover-item")` and everything will work just fine.

Now, this really only applies in cases where you have one animation for multiple items. Hover events are a good example of this. Instead of applying different hover events to different buttons for example, you can apply the same event to all buttons. But if you just want to disable hover events for one particular button, this is the way to go.